# Rotate an image from a X position to vertical position

Tags: python, opencv

Good afternoon everyone, I am using Python and opencv as programming language and computer vision framework and I am asking to myself if it is possible to rotate an image in an X position to a vertical position, I mean if an image is at 45 degrees, I want it rotated to be vertical 0 degrees.

I think there is a first step to detect the orientation of the image and after this rotate to avoid the original rotation and bring it vertical

Thank u so much for your help!

Comment: please take the [tour], then review [ask]. you should be looking for teaching materials.

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show an attempt with code. Please read the help section of this forum.

Comment: Yes I found the solution